# Symfony - Form - preferred choice for radio button

Tags: forms, symfony, radio-button

How to set a preferred choice in a form for radio button ?

What I need is to have a specific radio checked (the last of my 4 radio button) when I load the web page...

But I read that "preferred choice" is used just for a choice list not for radio or checkbox...
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#preferred-choices

I tried that:

```
->add('Offre', 'entity', array(
                        'class' => 'AVCMediasBundle:Offre',
                        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($parametre_langue) {
                            return $repository->createQueryBuilder('q')
                                ->where('q.id = 4')
                                ->orderBy('q.prix', 'DESC');
                        },
                        'property' => 'titre' . $parametre_langue,
                        'expanded' => true,
                        'multiple' => false,
                        'label' => false,
                        'preferred_choices' => array('1'),
                        'attr' => array(
                            'class' => 'langue_selector'
                        )
                    ));
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to "data" => '1' ?

Comment: yes but nothing happened...

Comment: may it's because the data in this field consists of entities, but you setting `preferred choices` to array of string? I mean, have you tried something like `'preferred_choices' => array($preferredEntity),`?

Comment: sad news from the documentation: "Note that preferred choices are only meaningful when rendering as a select element (i.e. expanded is false)"

Comment: Yes I do. but I found an other solution : I passed my choice directly in the entity... like that :                `$preferedOffer = $em->getRepository('AVCMediasBundle:Offre')->findOneById('4');
                $DetailTransaction->setOffre($preferedOffer);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to passed my choice directly in the entity when I load my form

```
 $preferedOffer = $em->getRepository('AVCMediasBundle:Offre')->findOneById('4');
 $DetailTransaction->setOffre($preferedOffer);
```